# Can't get rid of memory leak in c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm trying to dynamically increase the capacity of an array but I keep getting memory leaks when running with valgrind.
This is the code I'm running(nothing wrong with it shouldn't be the problem):

```
//My struct

struct ArrayList{

    int size;      //amount of items in a array
    int capacity; //the capacity of an array
    int* items;  //the array itself
};

//Dynamically create an array

ArrayList* createList(int m){
    ArrayList* n = new ArrayList;

    n->size = 0;
    n->capacity = m;
    n->items = new int[n->capacity];
    return n ;

}

//Destroy an array

void destroyList(ArrayList* List){
    delete[] List->items;
    delete List;

}
```

**The code to double the capacity(Where I get the memory leak):**

```
// double the capacity of an array by dynamically creating a new one and transfering the old values to it
void doubleCapacity(ArrayList* List){
    // save everything
    int saved_size = List->size;
    int saved_capacity = List->capacity;
    int* saved_items = new int[List->size];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < List->size;i++){
        saved_items[i] = List->items[i];
    }
    // load everything
    destroyList(List);
    List->size = saved_size;
    List->capacity = saved_capacity*2;
    List->items = new int[List->capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < List->size; i++){
        List->items[i] = saved_items[i];
        }
    delete[] saved_items;
}
```

My main that tests the code for doublecapacity.

```
int main() {
    // Run tests
    ArrayList* l = createList(4);
    l->size++;
    l->items[0] = 1;
    cout << l->size << endl;
    cout << l->capacity << endl;
    cout << l->items[0] << endl;
    doubleCapacity(l);
    cout << l->size << endl;
    cout << l->capacity << endl;
    cout << l->items[0] << endl;
        destroyList(l);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After `destroyList(List);`, `List` is a dangling pointer because you called `delete List`. You don't want to destroy and recreate the entire list just to expand its internal storage buffer, and even if you were you're missing the "recreate" step.

Comment: Tactical note: When you have a `struct` or `class` without constructors and destructors, but supported by create and destroy functions, strongly consider making the create and destroy functions into constructors and destructors. Save you potentiality vast amounts of pain later.

Comment: Example: https://godbolt.org/z/4ocfn5qGf See how much simpler the program is with OOP? Note how the copying is disabled. That's because of [The Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). If you want to make a resource-owning, and the dynamically allocated memory is a resource, class copyable (or movable) you need to make certain the contained resource is copied (or moved) along with it.

Comment: If you'd like your memory leak problems to go away forever, the solution is simple:  don't use raw pointers to hold your dynamically-allocated objects; use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` instead.  That way you don't have to manually figure out every location where `delete` or `delete[]` needs to be called; in fact you'll never use the `delete` keyword at all, and isntead your memory deallocations will "just happen" at the right times.  It's a 5-minute change that will save you hours of debugging.

Comment: Here is a more condensed variant using `std::unique_ptr`s to do the memory management: https://godbolt.org/z/hMT4Txsj7 The advantage is is rather clear. Whatever you do do to this, you wont risk leaking your `array` member. Notice that swap moves the pointer around, but its ownership is always well-defined.

Comment: A better option  is to use `std::vector` instead of `std::unique_ptr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `doubleCapacity()` function is implemented all wrong.

It is creating a temporary array of the original `size` just to save a *redundant* copy of the current `items`. Then it creates a new array of the desired `capacity` and copies the temporary items into it. You don't need that temporary array at all, you can copy the original items directly into the final array.

More importantly, you are destroying the `ArrayList` object itself, so any access to its members after it has been destroyed is *undefined behavior*.

Try something more like this instead:

```
void doubleCapacity(ArrayList* List){   
    if (List->capacity > (std::numeric_limits<int>::max() / 2))
        throw std::overflow_error("capacity is too high to double");
    int new_capacity = List->capacity * 2;
    int* new_items = new int[new_capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < List->size; i++){
        new_items[i] = List->items[i];
    }
    delete[] List->Items;
    List->items = new_items;
    List->capacity = new_capacity;
}
```